# if condition is true, set all other column values to 0 - R

Tags: r, if-statement, multiple-columns, selection

I create a random dataset via:

```
#create dataset
first_column <- c(1:10) #random column
second_column <- c(1:10) #random column
third_column <- c(1:10) #random column
group <- c(1,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,1) #column used for selection

#merge columns
df <- data.frame(first_column, second_column, third_column, group)

#examine
print(df)
```

which outputs:

```
   first_column second_column third_column group
1             1             1            1     1
2             2             2            2     1
3             3             3            3     1
4             4             4            4     2
5             5             5            5     2
6             6             6            6     1
7             7             7            7     2
8             8             8            8     1
9             9             9            9     1
10           10            10           10     1
```

I would like to set the values of columns `first_column`, `second_column`, and `third_column` to 0 if the value of `group` is equal to 2 (while retaining the values if the value of `group` equals 1), which should result in:

```
   first_column second_column third_column group
1             1             1            1     1
2             2             2            2     1
3             3             3            3     1
4             0             0            0     2
5             0             0            0     2
6             6             6            6     1
7             0             0            0     2
8             8             8            8     1
9             9             9            9     1
10           10            10           10     1
```

What is the most convenient way to reach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could create the logical index with `group` as `i` and assign the columns 1 to 3 as 0

```
df[df$group == 2, 1:3] <- 0
```

-output

```
> df
   first_column second_column third_column group
1             1             1            1     1
2             2             2            2     1
3             3             3            3     1
4             0             0            0     2
5             0             0            0     2
6             6             6            6     1
7             0             0            0     2
8             8             8            8     1
9             9             9            9     1
10           10            10           10     1
```